# How enter in folder with one command?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, alias

I work a lot in two folders:

```
/home/valter/Dropbox/Development/git/valter

/home/valter/Dropbox/Development/git/company
```

I would like to create command like:

```
$valter
```

and enter in `/home/valter/Dropbox/Development/git/valter`

and

```
$company
```

and enter in `/home/valter/Dropbox/Development/git/company`

```
/home/valter/Dropbox/Development/git/company
```

I tried create some alias in `~/.bashrc` but nothing works so far.

```
alias valter="cd /home/valter/Dropbox/Development/git/valter/"
```

**update**

@mpy:

```
meniac chef: valter
No command 'valter' found, did you mean:
 Command 'qalter' from package 'torque-client' (universe)
 Command 'qalter' from package 'gridengine-client' (universe)
 Command 'qalter' from package 'torque-client-x11' (universe)
valter: command not found
```

Comment: The alias should work. Did you `source ~/.bashrc`? The `$` in `$company` means this is the prompt?! You can also define a variable `company=/home/valter/Dropbox/Development/git/company` and the use `cd $company` or (what is a benefit compared to the alias) use `cp something $company`.

Comment: yes mpy, I did in my `/home/valter/.bashrc`

Comment: What is the error when using the alias?

Comment: @ValterHenrique Please try in a new window/session.

Comment: it works Omid, please put this as answer so I can choose it! Thank you!

Comment: Pinging @OmidTahouri – Valter Henrique, you always need to explicitly @-mention users in order for them to receive a reply.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As requested, I'll post an answer, but `@mpy`'s suggestion would've also done the job.

You'll have to re-source your ~/.bashrc using `source ~/.bashrc` **or** establish a new session (which would source that for you).

Comment: Not sure how to mention/tag in an answer, so: @mpy

Comment: +1: I appreciate. Your merit is, that you formulated it more understandable `;)`

Comment: Credit where credit is due :)

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing `"`'s (quote) with `'`'s (single-quote) instead.

Also, make sure you reload your `.bashrc` either by starting a new terminal emulator window, or by doing `. .bashrc` in your home folder.